# Using PushStreamContent to upload from an HTTPClient

Tags: c#, http, file-upload, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I would like to upload a large amount of data to a web server *from* a client machine. I jumped right to PushStreamContent so I could write directly to the stream, as the results vary in size and can be rather large.

The flow is as follows:

```
User runs query > Reader Ready Event Fires > Begin Upload
```

Once the ready event is fired, the listener picks it up and iterates over the result set, uploading the data as a multipart form:

```
Console.WriteLine("Query ready, uploading");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024], form = new byte[200];
        int offset = 0, byteCount = 0;
        StringBuilder rowBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        string builderS;
        var content = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, httpContent, transportContext) =>
        //using (System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.FileStream("test.txt", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            int bytes = 0;
            string boundary = createFormBoundary();
            httpContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            httpContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
            await stream.WriteAsync(form, 0, form.Length);
            form = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(createFormElement(boundary, "file"));
            await stream.WriteAsync(form, 0, form.Length);
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                foreach (var row in rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
                    {
                        rowBuilder.Append(row[i].Value);
                        if (i + 1 < row.Length)
                            rowBuilder.Append(',');
                        else
                        {
                            rowBuilder.Append("\r\n");
                        }
                    }
                    builderS = rowBuilder.ToString();
                    rowBuilder.Clear();
                    byteCount = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(builderS);
                    bytes += byteCount;
                    if (offset + byteCount > buffer.Length)
                    {
                        await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, offset);
                        offset = 0;
                        if (byteCount > buffer.Length)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Expanding buffer to {0} bytes", byteCount);
                            buffer = new byte[byteCount];
                        }
                    }
                    offset += System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builderS, 0, builderS.Length, buffer, offset);
                }
            });
            await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, offset);
            form = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(boundary);
            await stream.WriteAsync(form, 0, form.Length);
            await stream.FlushAsync(); //pretty sure this does nothing
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Wrote {0}.{1} megabytes of data", bytes / 1000000, bytes % 1000000);
```

I think the code above would work great if I were the server, just adding `stream.Close();` would finish it, however since I am the client here closing it causes an error (`TaskCancelled`). Waiting to read doesn't do anything either, I presume because the PushStreamContent doesn't end the request unless I explicitly close the stream. That being said, writing to a file produces exactly what I expect to be uploaded so everything writes perfectly.

Any ideas on what I can do here? I might be totally misusing `PushStreamContent` but it seems like this *should be* an appropriate use case.

Comment: How is this code being invoked?

Comment: @JonathanAmend It is triggered by a delegate event as a part of a separate class. The event is only fired once the reader is ready and has data, and provides an IEnumerable (GetRows()) that can then be used to read over the results. The method itself is async as well

Comment: AFAIK stream.Close() is the right way to tell the other side that they got the data. Where are you getting the TaskCancelled exception?

Comment: @JonathanAmend The taskcancelled occurs when I call `httpclient.putAsync("url", content);` sorry that isn't in the post. It only occurs once I close the stream though, the cause I presume is because there was no response from the remote server. Putting a read in does nothing though so I need to find some way to signal that I'm actually done writing and that the server should respond. I think...

Comment: Where are you putting the stream.Close()? It should be in place of stream.FlushAsync().

Comment: @JonathanAmend That's exactly where it was, I thought perhaps calling flush would trigger the response but no luck there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution is a little confusing at first but it seems to make sense and perhaps more importantly, it works:

```
using(var content = new MultipartFormDataContent()) 
{
  var pushContent = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, httpContent, transportContext) =>
  { 
    //do the stream writing stuff
    stream.Close();
  });
  content.add(pushContent);
  //post, put, etc. content here
}
```

This works because the stream passed to the `PushStreamContent` method is not the actual request stream, it's a stream handled by the `HttpClient`, just like adding a file to a request stream. As a result, closing it signals the end of input for this part of the `HttpContent` and allows the request to be finalized.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!