# Using HttpClient to upload a large payload without buffering

Tags: .net, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I am using HttpClient to send a POST request containing a large mutlipart payload.  As it turns out HttpClient is buffering the entire request and it is quite easy to recreate an out of memory error by trying to send a large file.  HttpClient provides a nice framework for building a multipart payload, but is it possible to stop it from buffering the request?

I'm using .net 4.7.2

Edit:

I've even tried PushStreamContent:

```
byte[] binBuffer = new byte[4096];

int iRead = 0;
PushStreamContent partAttachment = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
{
    using (Stream strData = File.Open(@"c:\test\big.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        while ((iRead = strData.Read(binBuffer, 0, binBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            stream.Write(binBuffer, 0, iRead);
        };
    }
    stream.Close();
});
```

I get an OOM exception on the stream.Write once I hit around 2 gigs.

Comment: Use PushStreamContent like shown in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283334/using-pushstreamcontent-to-upload-from-an-httpclient

Comment: @DarrelMiller - PushStream still buffers, as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to work with the `HttpWebRequest` class to do it this.

Something like this:

```
HttpWebrequest request = _httpClient.Request(url, contentType);

request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

using( var stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
{
    await yourPayloadMessage.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PushStreamContent will allow you to send a stream of bytes without buffering.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage() {
   RequestUri = ... ,
   Method = HttpMethod.POST,
   Content = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, httpContent, transportContext) =>
       { 
          // write to the stream from where ever you are getting the bytes from
          stream.Close();
       })
};

await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

You can see from here https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/PushStreamContent.cs#L113 that all PushStreamContent does is it receives the network stream from the HttpClientHandler via the SerializeToStream method and allows you to write directly to it.

I have a vague recollection of there being an issue with early versions of .NET 4 that actually prevented using chunked transport encoding.  I recall it being fixed but I'm not 100% certain of it.  If chunked encoding is not working it is a problem in the HttpClientHandler end of the pipeline, not in HttpClient or PushStreamContent.

Comment: I'm doing this on 4.7.2 framework and I still get an out of memory exception. on the stream.Write.  See edit to my original post.

Comment: @Jeremy Is this just a "stock" HttpClient instance using HttpClientHandler?  No DelegatingHandlers?